# Give Button and Text on the same line and text to be center of button

Tags: html, css, display

```
<input type="button" class="click" id="click" value="Click" style="width: 45px; margin-top: 1.5%; height: 20px; text-align: center; color: white; background: #23b7e5; font-size: 13px; border-color: #23b7e5; border-radius:2px; padding: 0px; "> 

    <label class="control-label" style="border: thin red solid; margin-top: 10px;">Here to find location</label>
```

I want button and text box in the same line which i got but i am not getting text to be center of button. I get this output. I want "Here to find location" to be center of button.

Thank You.
Any help would be grateful.

[image]

Comment: share button code too..

Comment: I have updated the question. in that there is a button code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`display: inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` will do the trick.

```css
input, label{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="click" id="click" value="Click" style="width: 45px; height: 20px; text-align: center; color: white; background: #23b7e5; font-size: 13px; border-color: #23b7e5; border-radius:2px; padding: 0px; "> 

    <label class="control-label" style="border: thin red solid;">Here to find location</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```html
<button>Click</button><input type="text" value =" Here The Location"/>
```

Comment: I don't want  textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You have given margin-top:1.5%; to input and margin-top:10px to label, you should use same margin value for both

```css
input{
  float:left;
  width: 45px;
  margin-top:10px; 
  height: 20px; 
  text-align: center; 
  color: white;
  background: #23b7e5; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  border-color: #23b7e5;
  border-radius:2px; 
  padding: 0px; 
  }
.control-label{
  float:left;
  border: thin red solid; 
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="click" id="click" value="Click" style=""> 

    <label class="control-label" style="">Here to find location</label>
```