# Display Text and Button on same line in table cell from HTML Template for Angular Directive

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, css-tables

I currently have a Angular search function implemented [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-mbb53i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fread-more.component.ts) that allows a user to search for courses.

This utilizes a [read-more directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859181/6521206) that shows a preview of the description and keywords and allows users to toggle to see more of the text.  I converted the `see more` hyperlink to a button, and either way the button or the text appear below the course description / keywords and I would like for this toggle to show up next to the words instead of on its own line.

```
<div [innerHTML]="currentText"> </div>
<button (click)="toggleView()" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"> 
    <i [class.hidden]="hideToggle" [ngClass]="isCollapsed ? 'fa fa-plus': 'fa fa-minus'"> </i></button>
```

I've tried solutions such as [wrapping them in divs and using `display:inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10451583/6521206)

```
<div id="block_container">
    <div id="bloc1"> <div [innerHTML]="currentText"> </div> </div>
    <div id="bloc2">
     <button (click)="toggleView()" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"> 
    <i [class.hidden]="hideToggle" [ngClass]="isCollapsed ? 'fa fa-plus': 'fa fa-minus'"> </i></button> </div>
</div>
```

and have tried [`display: inline-block`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889121/give-button-and-text-on-the-same-line-and-text-to-be-center-of-button), among others, but can't figure it out.

Is there an issue with it being inside a table cell or part of an Angular template?  Any pointers would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: by the way why do you use `[innerHTML]` use `<div>{{ currentText}} </div>`

Comment: use `display: inline-block` to `bloc1` and `bloc2` not to wrap div

Comment: I just utilized the implementation as it was given, is it cleaner to use the string interpolation?

Comment: or use `display:flex` to `block_container`

Comment: `display:flex` sends the button toggle all the way to the top right of the cell, I'd like for it to show next to the end of the snippet preview.  and `display: inline-block` doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: you want the button in the end of same line or in new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use     `display:flex;` to `#block_container`** if you use `inline` to childs `#bloc1, #bloc2`.

```
#bloc1, #bloc2
{
    display:inline;
}
```

See code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-vpax2x?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: I realized that I do need `<div [innerHTML]="currentText"> </div>` instead of `<div>{{currentText}} </div>` in order to make the highlight pipe work.  How would I adapt the solution in this case?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping them inside the table with 1 row elements

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><div1>...</div></td>
      <td><div2>...</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```